# React Application MSAL authentication unable to read config values

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, yaml, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I have an Azure Static Web App.

[image]

Since I don’t have enough permission, I’m unable to view the config settings of this app (REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID, REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID, REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID, REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI).

[image]

When I click on ***URL***, I see it is unable to read these values from config settings.

> Uncaught (in promise) ClientAuthError: endpoints_resolution_error: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints. Check your authority and verify the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint returns the required endpoints. Attempted to retrieve endpoints from: https://login.microsoftonline.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

It should have been:

> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"

Here is my code:

```
import { Configuration } from "@azure/msal-browser";

// Config object to be passed to Msal on creation
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID}`,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID}`,
        redirectUri: "/",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "/"
    }
};

// scopes
export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: [`api://${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID}/user_impersonation`]
  };

// endpoints 
export const config = {
    endpoint: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI}/api/v1/items`
};
```

Packages I use:

```
 "@azure/msal-browser",
 "@azure/msal-common",
 "@azure/msal-react"
```

Is there another way I can provide these values per environment instead via config settings? Maybe via YAML? I have to set these values for TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4, INT, UA, PROD environments.

Answer (score 0):

The MSAL `ClientAuthError` error means `process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID` is null or empty. Regarding values per env, take a look to [Customizing Environment Variables for Arbitrary Build Environments.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#customizing-environment-variables-for-arbitrary-build-environments)